# Optimize SQL query with JOIN for OR condition (MariaDB)

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization, mariadb-10.5

After simplifying a huge SQL query I have an easy query like this:

```
SELECT billing.id, payments.id 
FROM billing
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.billing_id = billing.id
WHERE billing.email = 'foo' OR payments.txn = 'bar';
```

It takes ~0.5 sec to execute. Of cause the relevant columns have BTREE indexes.

This is what EXPLAIN tells me:

```
1   SIMPLE  billing     index   email       email       1027    NULL          99464 Using index 
1   SIMPLE  payments    ref     billing_id  billing_id  5       db.billing.id   1   Using where
```

If I remove any of the OR-conditions or if I change OR to AND the query executes within 0.001 sec.

Any ideas how fix the performance without rewriting the query by UNION statement.

SQL Server version is 10.5.22-MariaDB (can be changed if needed).

Comment: Surely if payments.billing_id = billing.id
WHERE billing.email = 'foo' is true then OR payments.email = 'foo' is redundant? ..sample data would help clarify

Comment: The column names don't matter actually.

Comment: ??your last comment suggests you did not understand my comment..please add table definitions and representative sample data as text.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.